# How to pass a list of parameters to workers in Julia Distributed

Tags: julia, distributed

with Julia 1.5.3, I wanted to pass a list or parameters to the distributed workers.

I first tried in a non distributed way :

```
using Distributed

@everywhere begin 
    using SharedArrays

    solve(a,b,c) = return (1,2,3)

    d_rates = LinRange(0.01, 0.33, 5)
    m_rates = LinRange(0.01, 0.25, 5)
    population_size = 10^3
    max_iterations_perloop = 10^3
    nb_repeats = 2

    nb_params = length(d_rates)*length(m_rates)*nb_repeats
    para = enumerate(Base.product(d_rates, m_rates, population_size, max_iterations_perloop, 1:nb_repeats))

    results = SharedArray{Tuple{Int, Int, Int}}(nb_params)
end

for (y , x) in para
    results[y] = solve(x[1], x[2], x[3])
end
```

which worked fine. And then changed the final loop to:

```
@sync @distributed for (y , x) in para
    results[y] = solve(x[1], x[2], x[3])
end
```

I then got an error (truncated):

```
ERROR: LoadError: TaskFailedException:
MethodError: no method matching firstindex(::Base.Iterators.Enumerate{Base.Iterators.ProductIterator{Tuple{LinRange{Float64},LinRange{Float64},Int64,Int64,UnitRange{Int64}}}})
Closest candidates are:
  firstindex(::Cmd) at process.jl:638
  firstindex(::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:599
  firstindex(::Base64.Buffer) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Base64/src/buffer.jl:18
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::Distributed.var"#159#161"{var"#271#272",Base.Iterators.Enumerate{Base.Iterators.ProductIterator{Tuple{LinRange{Float64},LinRange{Float64},Int64,Int64,UnitRange{Int64}}}}})() at ./task.jl:332
Stacktrace:
 [1] sync_end(::Channel{Any}) at ./task.jl:314
 [2] top-level scope at task.jl:333
 [3] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1088
 [4] include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1096
 [5] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at ./essentials.jl:710
 [6] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./essentials.jl:709
```

Is it possible to pass such a list, if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that all your workers are on a single server and that you have actually added some workers using the `addprocs` command. The first problem with your code is that you create the `SharedArray` on all workers. Rather than that the syntax of a `SharedArray` is the following:

```
help?> SharedArray

  SharedArray{T}(dims::NTuple; init=false, pids=Int[])
  SharedArray{T,N}(...)

  Construct a SharedArray of a bits type T and size dims across the processes specified by pids - all of which have to be on the same host. (...)
```

This means that you create `SharedArray` only once from the master worker and you can specify the workers that are aware of it using the `pids` argument (if you do not specify `pids` all worker processes have the access).

Hence your code will look like this:

```
using Distributed, SharedArrays
addprocs(4)
@everywhere using SharedArrays

@everywhere solve(a,b,c) = return (1,2,3)

#(...) # your setup code without @everywhere

results = SharedArray{Tuple{Int, Int, Int}}(nb_params)

@sync @distributed for (y , x) in collect(para)
    results[y] = solve(x[1], x[2], x[3])
end
```

Note that you will need `collect` because `@distributed` macro needs to know the size of the `Vector` and it does not work good with iterators.